# Enviar email en Outlook desde cuenta no predeterminada

Tags: c#, outlook

Desde mi programa necesito enviar emails a través de Outlook 2010 pero usando una determinada cuenta (No a través de la cuenta predeterminada) desde mi Outlook.

EJEMPLO del escenario:

Los emails deben depositarse en la bandeja de salida (outbox) de la cuenta email_2.

Mi outlook tiene 3 cuentas de email (desde un Exchange Server)

- email_1 (predeterminada)
- email_2
- email_3

Lo intento con este código a traves de `SendUsingAccount`, que busca o encuentra la cuenta de email existente en Outlook:

**Clase** para buscar la cuenta email:

```
public static Outlook.Account GetAccountForEmailAddress(Outlook.Application application, string smtpAddress)
{
     // Loop sobre la coleccion de cuentas de email de la actual sesion de outlook.
     Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts;
     foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
     {
         // Cuando encuentra la cuenta email, entonces devuelve la cuenta email.
         if (account.SmtpAddress == smtpAddress) return account;
     }
     throw new System.Exception(string.Format("No Account with SmtpAddress: {0} exists!", smtpAddress));
}
```

Desde este código llamo a a la clase `GetAccountForEmailAddress`:

```
Outlook.Account account = GetAccountForEmailAddress(oApp , "email_2");
oMsg.SendUsingAccount = account;
```

LO RARO:

Cuando pruebo esto en mi PC de desarrollo funciona.
La diferencia es que en mi PC de desarrollo (local), mi Outlook tiene 3 cuentas de email, una de *Hotmail*, otra de *Gmail* y otra de *Yahoo*.

Pero cuando lo pruebo en (red) con mi *Outlook* con 3 cuentas de email pero desde el Exchange Server, no funciona.....aparentemente no encuentra la cuenta de email aunque esta existe.

Por otro lado, si utilizo sencillamente `SentOnBehalfOfName`, esto sencillamente define el email que aparecerá como el que envía, pero el email se almacena en la bandeja de salida (outbox) de la cuenta email predeterminada.

¿Por qué no funciona esta clase?

¿Cómo puedo yo enviar un email a traves de la cuenta email que se elija (el email debe depositarse en la bandeja de salida) de Outlook, cuando estas cuentas email están en un Exchange Server?